# Migration VSTS cloud to self-hosted TFS Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migrate

I need to migrate our online VSTS to our own self-hosted TFS 2017 server.
Is there a way to do it and preserve history?

Answer (score 1):

No, there currently is no easy way to move from Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) back to Azure DevOps Server (formerly TFS) with full fidelity.

There are tools that can migrate work items over. There are tools that can migrate git over. There are tools that can migrate TFVC over (but all IDs change)... But there are so many other things potentially in your Team Projects (like Test results, builds, package management etc)...

In the end getting (mostly) everything from Azure DevOps into Azure DevOps Server should be doable, but you may loose links between items, lose some history and will likely reset dates and author data in the process.

Comment: ugh, i misread his question ;)